# Barbecue hose replacement

Tags: fitting, gas-burner

My barbecue hose shows pretty serious cracks, after 10 years. Assuming I can find a replacement part, can I simply screw it in? Is there some tape or substance I need to put on the threads to be sure it is sealed correctly? Any special care I should apply?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: visit a store that sells barbecues

Comment: The part that you replace is the hose AND regulator, like this: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01GZPBCPU/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_c_api_1EboBbX2V479P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are usually flair seals, (metal to metal) no sealing compound is needed if they are and if used can create leaks, the best thing is to get some "gas leak bubble solution) or some soapy water and spray the fitting once pressurized, no bubbles you are good to start grilling.